# I can't get the thumbnail of the video with PHPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get the thumbnail of the chosen video. When testing on the simulator, everything is fine.
But when testing on my own iPhone with iOS 17, I get the error:

> "...you don't have permission to view it".

Please, would anyone know why this private path is returned when testing on the device?
I researched some things a little, and found relationships with App Sandbox & Entitlements, but I'm still researching and learning more about it.

The code:

```
guard results.count > 0 else { return } 
     for asset in results {
         if asset.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
             asset.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { [weak self] movie, _ in
                guard let self, let url = movie as? NSURL, let _movie: String = url.absoluteString else { return }
                print(movie)
                ...
```

> ```
> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/.../&type=3&mode=2&loc=true&cap=true.mov
> ```

The thumbnail code: When trying to get the video thumbnail with the above result

```
 extension URL {
     func thumbnailForMovie() throws -> UIImage? {
        do {
            let _asset = AVURLAsset(url: self, options: nil)
            let generatorImage = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: _asset)
            generatorImage.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let timestamp = _asset.duration
            let cgImage = try generatorImage.copyCGImage(at: timestamp, actualTime: nil)
            let _thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return _thumbnail
        } catch {
           throw error ....
```

If anyone can help me!! Thanks.